# Keep a projected graph in synch with persisted graph in Neo4j GDS

Tags: neo4j

I have a large dataset to run a specific Graph Data Science algorithm on.

The functional requirement is that the algorithm **will be run often** and that the dataset **changes in real-time**.

As I understand, in order to run an algorithm I have to project the persistent graph into memory first.

But, GDS only provides a projection of the whole dataset once (as a (filtered) snapshot), therefore, on each change to my dataset (i.e. a new relationship edge added between two nodes), I have to rerun the projection again, which seems **quite an ineffective** thing to do.

Is there a generic way to circumvent this and keep the Projection properly in sync with the persistent graph?

Comment: Unfortunartely, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Tomaž Bratanič's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258583/keep-a-projected-graph-in-synch-with-persisted-graph-in-neo4j-gds#comment129383621_73258583), it isn't possible at the moment.